# backbone.js nested object attribute with stickit.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-stickit

I am using stickit.js to achieve two way data binding. I am please to know how do I bind stickit with nested object attribute. For an E.g.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name: {
            first: 'James',
            last: 'White'
        }
    }
});
```

I wonder it is possible to bind a text input some thing like this.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="first-name"/>


bindings: {
    '.first-name': 'name.first'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a feature called *computeds*.

Computeds are binding fields that are calculated on the fly and may be compounds of other model fields.

I can't see this kind of feature in the stickit docs, though. So you could give the really excellent model-binding library [backbone-epoxy](http://epoxyjs.org/tutorials.html#computed-attributes) a shot. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLBCA/) for you.

```
var Person = Backbone.Epoxy.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name: {
            first: 'James',
            last: 'White'
        }
    },
    computeds: {
        fullname: function() {
            return this.get('name').first + ' ' + this.get('name').last;
        }
    }
});

var view = new Backbone.Epoxy.View({
    el: '#app',
    model: new Person()
});
```

And the html:

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:fullname" />
</div>
```